# Difference between popular CMake build system and genproj tool for OpenCASCADE

Tags: visual-c++, build, project, setup-project, opencascade

While exploring about the platform setup for OpenCASCADE, I came to know about WOK commands which arent needed for **CMake** build system to use with OpenCASCADE
However another option of **genproj** tool (for which I havent yet found any exe but DLLs..) to be used with MSVC+ in built compiler so that we dont need any gcc installation

Whats the difference between the twos and which one is better and easier??
Also suggest me how to download and install and setup genproj on windows

Answer (score 0):

OCCT project provided the following build systems:

- **CMake**. This is the main building system since OCCT 7.0.0.
  It allows building OCCT for almost every supported target platform.
- **WOK**. This *was* an in-house building system used by OCCT *before* 7.0.0 release.
  The tool handled classes defined in **CDL** (CAS.CADE definition language) files (WOK generated C++ header files from CDL) and supported building in a distributed environment (e.g. local WOK setup builds only modified source files and reused unmodified binary / object files from local network). WOK support has been discontinued since OCCT 7.5.0 and unlikely will be able building up-to-date OCCT sources (although project structure remains compatible with WOK).
- **genproj**. This is a Tcl script allowing to generate project for building OCCT using Visual Studio (2010+), Code::Blocks, XCode and Qt Creator. This script has been initially extracted from WOK package (where it was implemented as command `wgenproj` in it's shell) and now maintained independently from it.
- **qmake**. Experimental `adm/qmake` solution can be opened directly from QtCreator without CMake plugin (the project files will be generated recursively by `qmake`). Although header files generation (filling in `inc` folder) still should be done using `genproj` (`qmake` scripting capabilities were found too limited for this staff).

**genproj** doesn't require any DLLs or EXE files - it comes with OCCT itself and requires Tcl interpreter. On Windows platform it can be executed with `genconf.bat` and `genproj.bat` batch scripts in the root of OCCT source code folder. At first launch it will ask to put a path to `tclsh.exe`.

While **CMake** is the main building tool for OCCT project, **genproj** remains maintained and used by (some) developers - mostly due to personal habits and hatred to CMake. They differences of genproj from CMake that could be considered as advantages in some cases:

- Generated project files can be moved to another location / computer without necessity to re-generate them.
- Simplified 3rd-party dependency search tool **genconf** with GUI based on Tcl/Tk.
- Batch-script environment/configuration files (**env.bat** and **custom.bat**), although CMake script in OCCT emulates similar files.
- Generated Visual Studio solution contains Debug+Release and 32bit/64bit configurations.
- Running Draw Harness and regression tests can be started directly from Visual Studio (without building any `INSTALL` target).
- No problems with `CMakeCache.txt`.

**Limitations of genproj**:

- No CMake configuration files. Other CMake-based projects would not be able re-using configuration files to simplify 3rd-party setup.
- Regeneration of project files should be called explicitly.
- Out-of-source builds are not supported (however, each configuration is put into dedicated sub-folder).
- No `INSTALL` target.
- No PCH (pre-compiler header file) generation.

It should be noted, that several attempts have been done to make compiler / linker flags consistent between CMake and genproj, but in reality they may be different.